# Python Turtle Graphics not opening and running

Tags: python-3.9

I tried to run my turtle code on vs code but, it doesn't run! it has no errors or bugs also. And I have a similar turtle project but it runs and opens Python Turtle Graphics! but this one doesn't! Here is the code:

```html
from turtle import Turtle, Screen



def draw_square(some_turtle):
    for _ in range(4):
        some_turtle.forward(200)
        some_turtle.right(90)

def draw_art():
    brad = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    brad.color("yellow")
    brad.pensize(2)
    brad.speed(0)
    for _ in range(36):
        draw_square(brad)
        brad.right(10)
    # Turtle Angie    
    angie = Turtle(shape="turtle")
    angie.color("blue")
    angie.pensize(2)
    angie.speed(0)
    size = 1
    for _ in range(300):
        angie.forward(size)
    angie.right(91)
    size += 1
    
    window = Screen()
    window.bgcolor("black")

    draw_art()

    window.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your program to work you have to take out the `draw_art()` because it is inside the definition. Instead it needs to be outside of the definition.